# Как был создан свободный мир в игре “no man sky”?

Tags: opengl, directx, теория

Попробовал я поработать в [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/), и решил создать свободный мир размером с одну звездную систему.
Этого оказалось слишком сложно сделать. И запихнуть всю звёздную систему в одну сцену не выдает.

По сему у меня появился вопрос как же реализован мир [no man sky](https://www.nomanssky.com/) и считывая что там множество звёздных систем ?

Также мне показали движёк Unreal Engine  там сцена размером  48 км создаётся. А мне нужен мир

*Я слышал про механизм перехода сцен, но как именно в такой большой игре это реализовано это мне непонятно.*

---

**Также моя цель создать мир размером с звездную систему размером с солнечную.**

Также возможно уже открывал такой вопрос (**как создать сцену размером с звездную систему ?** )  но увы удалили его.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем я нашёл ответ после просмотра многих книг по DirectX обзорным методом.

В общем ответ подсказали старые игры из двухтысячных. Когда ты идешь по территории и доходишь до её границы "выпрыгивает" загрузочный экран и происходит загрузка уровня.

И тут до меня дошло !!!!

**Что по сути сцена "коробка" не меняется, меняются объекты на сцене !**

> Тут распишу алгоритм от рисовки "взлета с планеты и полет к
>   следующей планете", 
>       также представим что мы уже отрисовали ландшафт и задали размер сцены 
>       "коробки", а также установили картинку стенок сцены "полуденный_зной.jpg":
>
> - взлетаем вверх, поднимаемся к границе сцены"коробки". 
>        Назовём это уровень <<атмосфера>>.
> - после подлета к верхней границе переносим камеру в центр коробки
>        перерисовываем ландшафт, превращаем ландшафт в полусферу.Также 
>        меняем картинку стенок сцены"коробки" на картинку "граничная_стратосфера.jpg". 
>        Назовём это уровень <<стратосфера>>.
> - после подлёта к верхней границе переносим камеру в центр коробки
>        перерисовываем полусферу, превращаем полусферу в сферу.
>        Также меняем картинку стенок сцены"коробки" на картинку "бездонный_космос.jpg". 
>        Назовём это уровень <<космос>>.
> - Тут уже мы в космосе :3 находим иную ближайшую сферу и приближаемся к ней. 
>        После приближения на достаточное расстояние, происходит переход 
>        с уровня <<космос>> на уровень <<стратосфера>>.
> - Стремимся в центр полусферы и переходим на уровень атмосфера, 
>        всё мы на другой планете (для удобства для второй планеты стоит
>        изменить шейдеры, либо просто изменить их цвета). **теперь мы всё космонавты :3**

Я долго не мог понять, пока не осознал что  начиная с 201n года (в [x3 terran conflict](https://www.egosoft.com/news/current_ru.php) переходы ещё были) многопоточность стала столь хороша, а также компьютерные мощности "пользователей" возросли на столько что переходы делаются на "раз два", ака **бесшовный мир**.

Comment: Почему сразу 201n? GTA 3, например, вышла в 2001 году, тогдашних мощностей вполне хватало.

Comment: @Yaant я бы сказал когда умерли в коммерческих играх переходы, а не когда появился первый бесшовный мир. Но спасибо за интересную ссылку :3

Comment: Ну, так-то мир без переходов был и в древнейшем MS Flight Simulator, с увеличением детализации в каждой новой версии. А бесшовные звёздные системы с посадками на планеты - в Elite 2

Comment: @Yaant В Elite 2 нету ни теней ни шейдеров . Не спорю, но как по мне это ещё очень далеко да приемлемого графона (я приемлю графон от diretcx10 простенькой реализации )

Comment: Так само собой, откуда 1993 году шейдеры? Но мне кажется, Вы смешиваете архитектурное решение с рендерингом. Возьмите движок от Elite 2, добавьте к нему шейдеры с тенями, ну будет она требовать не 2 Мб оперативки, а 2 Гб, но суть-то не изменится. PS. Вот вам еще [Space Engine](http://spaceengine.org/ru). Бесшовная вселенная (даже не галактика) с более чем приемлемым графоном. Но современная, да.

Comment: @Yaant _Возьмите движок от Elite 2, добавьте к нему шейдеры с тенями, ну будет она требовать не 2 Мб оперативки, а 2 Гб, но суть-то не изменится._ - увы я знаю свой уровень, у меня не выдет, слишком сложно для меня. Также стоит заметить что Space Engine я когда искал движок его даже не нашёл. Спасибо посмотрю (вся проблема можно ли будет на нём сделать игру).

Comment: @Yaant Q: Существует ли SpaceEngine SDK? Могу я использовать движок для создания своей игры?
A: Пока что нет. Движок находится в стадии разработки, и много работы ещё предстоит. Но когда основная работа будет сделана, будет создан SDK.